# Is this formula really the nine axioms?

Tags: axioms, lambda-calculus

I was reading a note from guardian.uk called *[What lurks beneath a scientist's lab coat?](http://www.guardian.co.uk/books/gallery/2011/nov/27/science-ink-tattoo-design-pictures#/?picture=382370726)*, a little gallery of geeky-tattoos.

However, [number 11](http://www.guardian.co.uk/books/gallery/2011/nov/27/science-ink-tattoo-design-pictures#/?picture=382370726&index=10) in the series has the following image and caption text:

[image: Nine axioms?]

> 'From these nine axioms,' writes Turing Eret, a software designer in
>   Colarado, 'one can derive all of mathematics – a field you can likely
>   tell that I love dearly'

**Is that really so? Are those the nine axioms?** (I guess it means the ZF axioms) **If so, how are they expressed like that?** (Last question meaning: how does that expression imply the nine axioms?)

I tried to search it around but searching formulas is really hard. Also, Google and TinEye image search wouldn't produce anything relevant.

I really suck at math but I love it, so forgive me if I'm asking something stupid.

Comment: No. Those are not the axioms ZF set theory. (To be precise there are infinitely many ZF set theory "axioms". The "nine" axioms actually include a few axiom schema). The picture is that of some statement of lambda-calculus.

Comment: @BillCook Thanks! Took me a while to understand the statement about ZF schematic but re-reading some references, it made sense to me.

Comment: those were some interesting tatoos. I wonder if any of the other tatoos are as inaccurately labeled as the one you posted above. If so, I'd skip buying the book. :)

Comment: It looks like they just misplaced the caption.  Here is an arm (same person?) with ZF (or is it ZFC?) written on it: https://jux.com/gallery/34661.  Google for "carl zimmer" "nine axioms", it is the first link.

Comment: Main page of the other gallery of the same work: https://scienceink.jux.com/.  Unfortunately it doesn't feature the Y combinator image so who knows what he has to say about it (buy the book?).

Comment: @Dan Unfortunately it seems the link is no longer there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is called a [Y combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator).  This particular one was invented by Haskell Curry according to the Wikipedia page.  It has little to do with set theory and I am not sure what are the "nine axioms" referred to.  I know it as being a useful tool in constructing a [LISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LISP)-like language from [combinator calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus).  It has the effect of applying its argument to itself, i.e. Yx -> x(Yx) -> x(x(Yx)), which can be used to implement recursion.  This is not the only expression with such an effect; scroll down the Wikipedia page to see some other examples of Y combinators.

Answer (score 10):

That's my arm! Yeah, it was incorrectly labelled in the Guardian article. That is the Y Combinator as others have mentioned. My OTHER tattoo are the ZFC axioms. In the book, both tattoos are pictured but only the ZFC one is described. A bit unfortunate, but oh well. What can you do?